# "Mix it round." vs "Mix it."

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Someone is showing how to make a cake. And after putting the ingredients into a bowl, there comes this sentence:

**Mix it round.** [Tweenies](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JdyNbVEjFqo) (see 8:05-8:10)

I, a non-native English speaker, wouldn't imagine adding the word **"round"** and simply say:

**Mix it.**

So, I wonder, why **"...round"**? Isn't **"Mix it"** enough?

Comment: Note, children's shows often use whimsically non-standard dialogue. I hope no English learner adopts Elmo's problems with first-person pronouns! But this isn't really non-standard, just whimsical. Note, so there's no confusion, this is not the adjective "round" (circular in shape), but an adverb, interchangeable with "around," and often spelled "'round," as in "Here we go 'round the mulberry bush."

Comment: Any number of prepositions can be added after mix.  They all make sense. *Mix it up.  Mix it round.  Mix it in.  Mix it around.*  All make sense and mean roughly the same thing.  Mixing mixes things up, around, and in.

Comment: While *round* is not absolutely needed here, there are ways to mix batter that do not *mix it round*: Folding, beating, and barely blending.

Comment: You'll note that the ***cartoon*** speaker is ***imitating the action*** while stressing the drawn-out word ***round***. The show is clearly intended to teach Anglophone children something about cake-making (which often uses ready-made ***cake mix***). It's not intended to teach non-Anglophones how we normally use the word ***mix*** as a verb. Unlike ***turn it round*** and ***twist it round*** the verb ***mix*** isn't normally coupled with ***round***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While some may say 'mix it round' is not necessary, others may feel that 'mix' alone does not fully convey the required meaning.

'Mix' is defined in Cambridge this way:

> to (cause different substances to) combine, so that the result cannot easily be separated into its parts.

So 'mix' simply means to combine. In cookery, mixing often means *stirring* (which is what is implied by 'mix around'), but not always! There are many methods of mixing ingredients besides stirring, such as *folding, whisking, beating*, or  *creaming*, and recipes will usually specify which is required.

So '*mix around*' adds important details on *how* to mix it - by stirring. The language is just simplified somewhat for children.

And of course, if there was never a need to specify how something should be mixed then James Bond could have saved a lot of time when ordering his Martinis ("shaken, not stirred").

Answer (score 1):

You're right, "Mix it" is perfectly enough! In fact, that's the more common way to say it.

Adding "round" is most probably done either for emphasis (being more clear to a child who is new to baking) or rhyming (to make the instructions more catchy and memorable).